# Populating a complex Data Grid with with array data

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui, react-proptypes

I am trying to create a complex table using the mapping feature with React but i'm struggling to find any good resources that show how large arrays can be populated into tables. In the code below am I going about populating my tables the correct way? I am trying to create lines (createData) with all the fields displayed in brackets after the map. This would then create rows to go into my table.

I am trying to create a table with shortened key values that then expand out to show all the fields for each entry.

**const rows = [
{userDiveLogList.map((diveID, diveDate, diverUserNumber, diveTypeID, diveSpotID, diveSchoolNameID, diveCurrentID, diveVisibilityID, diveMaxDepth, diveNotes, diveVerifiedBySchool) => (
createData(diveID[i], diveDate[i], diverUserNumber[i], diveTypeID[i], diveSpotID[i], diveSchoolNameID[i], diveCurrentID[i], diveVisibilityID[i], diveMaxDepth[i], diveNotes[i], diveVerifiedBySchool[i])
))}]**

```
function createData(diveID, diveDate, diverUserNumber, diveTypeID,diveSpotID, diveSchoolNameID, diveCurrentID, diveVisibilityID, diveMaxDepth, diveNotes, diveVerifiedBySchool) {
    return {
        diverUserNumber,
        diveID,
        diveTypeID,
        diveSpotID,
        diveSchoolNameID,
        diveVerifiedBySchool,
        diveLog: [
            { dive: {diveID}, diveDate: {diveDate}, diverUserNumber: {diverUserNumber}, diveType: {diveTypeID}, diveSpot: {diveSpotID}, diveSchoolName: {diveSchoolNameID}, currentID: {diveCurrentID}, visibilityID: {diveVisibilityID}, diveMaxDepth: {diveMaxDepth}, diveNotes: {diveNotes}, diveVerifiedBySchool: {diveVerifiedBySchool} },
        ],
    };
}

function Row(props) {
    const {row} = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const classes = useRowStyles();

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <TableRow className={classes.root}>
                    <TableCell>
                        <IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                            {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon/> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon/>}
                        </IconButton>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.diverUserNumber}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.diveID}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.diveTypeID}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.diveSpotID}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.diveSchoolNameID}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.diveVerifiedBySchool}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell style={{paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0}} colSpan={6}>
                        <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                        <Box margin={1}>
                        <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">Dive details</Typography>
                            <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                               <TableHead>
                                  <TableRow>
                                  <TableCell>DiveID</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell>DiverUserNumber</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">DiveTypeID</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">DiveSpotID</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell>DiveSchoolName</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell>Current</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">Visibility</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">Max Depth</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">Notes</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">Verified</TableCell>
                                  </TableRow>
                                  </TableHead>
                                  <TableBody>{row.history.map((historyRow) => (
                                  <TableRow key={historyRow.diveDate}>
                                  <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.diveID}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.diveDate}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.diverUserNumber}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.diveTypeID}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.diveSpotID}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.diveSchoolNameID}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.diveCurrentID}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.diveVisibilityID}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.diveMaxDepth}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.diveNotes}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.diveVerifiedBySchool}</TableCell>
                                  </TableRow>
                                    ))}
                                    </TableBody>
                                </Table>
                            </Box>
                        </Collapse>
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

Row.propTypes = {
    row: PropTypes.shape({
        diverUserNumber: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        diveID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        diveTypeID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        diveSpotID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        diveSchoolName: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        diveVerifiedBySchool: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        diveLog: PropTypes.arrayOf(
            PropTypes.shape({
                diveID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                diveDate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
                diverUserNumber: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                diveTypeID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                diveSpotID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                diveSchoolNameID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                diveCurrentID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                diveVisibilityID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                diveMaxDepth: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                diveNotes: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                diveVerifiedBySchool: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
            }),
        ).isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
};

// un-collapsed dive date
**const rows = [
{userDiveLogList.map((diveID, diveDate, diverUserNumber, diveTypeID, diveSpotID, diveSchoolNameID, diveCurrentID, diveVisibilityID, diveMaxDepth, diveNotes, diveVerifiedBySchool) => (
    createData(diveID[i], diveDate[i], diverUserNumber[i], diveTypeID[i], diveSpotID[i], diveSchoolNameID[i], diveCurrentID[i], diveVisibilityID[i], diveMaxDepth[i], diveNotes[i], diveVerifiedBySchool[i])
))}]**

function CollapsibleTable() {
    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell />
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.diverUserNumber}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.diveID}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.diveTypeID}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.diveSpotID}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.diveSchoolNameID}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.diveVerifiedBySchool}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {rows.map((row) => (
                        <Row key={row.name} row={row} />
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}
```